# PAC Learnability of axis aligned squares

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

Ok, so I already know how the pac learnability of an axis aligned rectangle is demonstrated, that is we fix some distribution $D$ over $X$, define $R^* = R_{(a_1^*, b_1^*, a_2^*, b_2^*)}$ the rectangle that generates the labels. Also define $a_1 \geq a_1^*$ such that the probability mass with respect to $D$ of the rectangle $R_1 = R_{(a_1^*, a_1, a_2^*, b_2^*)}$ is exactly $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Similarly define $b_1, a_2, b_2$ such that the probability masses of $R_2, R_3$ and $R_4$ are exactly $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$.

My question is how could we prove the pac learnability for axis-aligned squares, where the class of all axis aligned squares in the plane is defined as

$
H = \{h_{(a_1, a_2, r)} : R^2 \rightarrow\{0,1\} | a_1, a_2, r \in R, r > 0\}
$

and a classifier $h_{(a_1, a_2, r)}$ is defined by:

$
 h_{(a_1, a_2, r)}(x_1,x_2) = \left\{
                            \begin{array}{ll}
                                1, \text{if }  a_1 \leq x_1 \leq a_1 + r, a_2 \leq x_2 \leq a_2 + r \\
                                0, \text{otherwise}
                            \end{array}
                            \right.
 $

Can we prove the pac-learnability of axis-aligned squares in the same manner as in rectangles? Thank you!